# Gmail Log in not working properly

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase, gmail

I have a mobile application where you need to login with either gmail or Facebook. The app is now available on google play, but I'm having a technical problem. 
When I plug my android device in my laptop and run the app the Gmail login works fine but when I download the app from google play and try logging in through gmail nothing happens; the app remains on the login screen. Anyone knows why I'm having this problem?

Here is my Authentication .java file:

```
package com.hallak.billdozer.activities;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.facebook.AccessToken;
import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.login.LoginManager;
import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthCredential;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.hallak.billdozer.R;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Created by Team Budget 2 on 2/28/17.
 * That class deals with authentication using Facebook and Gmail
 */

public class AuthActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        View.OnClickListener  {

    /**
     * Invokes Facebook login button
     */
    private LoginButton mLoginButton;

    /**
     * Registers a callback for changes to packages in current and managed profiles.
     */
    protected CallbackManager mCallbackManager;

    /**
     * Listens to any change in the user's authentication
     */
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;

    /**
     * The entry point of the Firebase Authentication SDK.
     */
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    /**
     * Invokes the GMail sign in button
     */
    private SignInButton mSignInButton;

    /**
     * The main entry point for Google Play services integration.
     */
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    /**
     * The entry point for accessing a Firebase Database.
     */
    private FirebaseDatabase mDatabase;

    /**
     * A Firebase reference represents a particular location in your Database and can be used for reading or writing data to that Database location.
     */
    private DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference;

    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;

    /**
     * This tag is used to be able to log events that happen in this activity
     */
    private static final String TAG = "Auth Activity";

    /**
     *  Basic application startup logic that should happen only once for the entire life of the activity.
     * @param savedInstanceState  Bundle object containing the activity's previously saved state. If the activity has never existed before, the value of the Bundle object is null.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Call the super class onCreate to complete the creation of activity like the view hierarchy
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //Initialize facebook SDK
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());

        // Set the user interface layout for this Activity
        // The layout file is defined in the project res/layout/main_activity.xml file
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        mDatabaseReference = mDatabase.getReference();

        // Configure sign-in to request the user's ID, email address, and basic
        // profile. ID and basic profile are included in DEFAULT_SIGN_IN.
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

        // Build a GoogleApiClient with access to the Google Sign-In API and the
        // options specified by gso.
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();

        // Set the dimensions of the sign-in button.
        mSignInButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
        mSignInButton.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_WIDE);

        //Initialize callback manager
        mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        //Assign the views to the corresponding variables
        mLoginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);

        //Assign the button permissions
        mLoginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("email", "public_profile"));

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        //Set an action listener to the sign in buton
        findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(this);

        //Listens to any change in the user's authentication
        mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                //Get currently logged in user
                final FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

                if (user != null) {
                    // User is signed in
                    Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());

                    //Check if any change occurs in the user's profile
                    mDatabaseReference.child("users").child(user.getUid()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        /**
                         * Called on data change, logs the changed value
                         * @param dataSnapshot get the data
                         */
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            // This method is called once with the initial value and again
                            // whenever data at this location is updated.
                            Map<String, Object> value = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                            Log.d(TAG, "Value is: " + value);
                        }

                        /**
                         * If we cannot read the changed values
                         * @param error the error thrown by Firebase
                         */
                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                            // Failed to read value
                            Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
                        }
                    });

                } else {
                    // User is signed out
                    Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
                }

                updateUI(user);
            }
        };

        //Assign the button a task

    }

    /**
     * Google Sign In
     */
    protected void signIn() {
        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            if (result.isSuccess()) {
                // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
                GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
                firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
            } else {
                // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
                updateUI(null);
            }
        }
        //Result returned from facebook
        else {
            mCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Handles Facebook Login
     * @param token User's access token
     */
    protected void handleFacebookAccessToken(AccessToken token) {
        Log.d(TAG, "handleFacebookAccessToken:" + token);

        AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(token.getToken());

        //Listen to the sign in process
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                        // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                        // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(AuthActivity.this, "Authentication failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        //If signing in succeeds, then store the user's information in the database
                        else {
                            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

                            updateUI(user);
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    /**
     * Handles Google's Login
     * @param acct Google account used to login
     */
    protected void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
        Log.d(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + acct.getId());

        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);

        //Listen to the sign in process

        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                        // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                        // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(AuthActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        //If signing in succeeds, then store the user's information in the database
                        else{
                            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

                            Log.d(TAG, "Saving user in Firebase");

                            updateUI(user);
                        }
                        // ...
                    }
                });
    }

    /**
     * Handle clicks on Facebook and Google's buttons
     * @param v
     */
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.sign_in_button:
                signIn();
                break;
            case R.id.com_facebook_button_xout:
                signOut();
                break;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Upon success/failure of the authentication return the desired page
     * @param user
     */
    protected void updateUI(FirebaseUser user){
        if(user != null){
            Intent i = new Intent(AuthActivity.this, SplashScreen.class);
            i.putExtra("userId",user.getUid());
            i.putExtra("userEmail", user.getEmail());
            i.putExtra("userName", user.getDisplayName());
            startActivity(i);
        }
        else{

        }
    }

    /**
     * Called upon the success of the authentication, listens to the User's auth state
     */
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }

    /**
     * Called upon the failure of the authentication, stops listening to the user's auth state
     */
    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mAuthListener != null) {
            mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Method called when an unresolvable error has occurred and Google APIs (including Sign-In) will not be available
     * @param connectionResult result of the connection to Google's APIs
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        // An unresolvable error has occurred and Google APIs (including Sign-In) will not
        // be available.
        Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailed:" + connectionResult);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Google Play Services error.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    /**
     * Sign out from the application
     */
    protected void signOut() {
        mAuth.signOut();
        LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();

        updateUI(null);
    }
}
```

And those are my dependencies in my build.gradle:

```
 dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.6.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.8.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.github.IntruderShanky:scatter-piechart:1.0.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```